# LINQ compare string and DB column type 'text'

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, linq

This is my error message `The data types text and varchar are incompatible in the equal to operator.` My code is something like

```
var result = db.Table.Where(x => x.columnA == "A").ToList();
```

I know the reason is the `columnA`'s type in DB is text so they can't match
and I can't update the DB scheme.

Could I do this by using LINQ to SQL?

**Update**

This is my DAO

```
[Required]
[StringLength(10)]
public string MessageName { get; set; }
```

Comment: does that work?
var result = db.Table.Where(x => x.columnA.ToString() == "A").ToList();

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`TEXT` columns do not support the equal to operator, even in SQL.

You must make it so your query translates into a `LIKE` operator, which can be achieved with either `Contains` (`LIKE '%str%'`), `StartsWith` (`LIKE '%str'`) or `EndsWith` (`LIKE '%str'`).

If you need strict equality, something like this should work:

```
var result = db.Table.Where(x => x.columnA.StartsWith("A") &&
                                 x.columnA.EndsWith("A")).ToList();
```

Comment: I think it will wok and thanks for your explain but it take too loooong time, haha.

Comment: While you are right in general, that sample doesn't provide a strict equality. For example a field containing "A blah blah A" would match. You can provide == with Linq To SQL using ToString(). However, it would be nonsense to do == on a Text field.

Comment: @CetinBasoz you are right. It's a old project and I can't update that part

Comment: didnt work, i got `Argument data type ntext is invalid for argument 1 of left function`

Answer (score 3):

you can use this (i haven't tested the code)

```
var result = db.Table.Where(x => x.columnA.Contains("A")).ToList();
```

Answer (score 2):

Can you cast the Column in question to a string? I haven't got any way to test this as I don't have a DB with a `Text` type.

```
var result = db.Table.Where(x => x.columnA.ToString() == "A").ToList();
```

Comment: It is string at begining

Comment: This one is the actual answer to the OP's question.

Comment: @CetinBasoz This will cause same error at my question. And you can see the Update part in my question. columnA is string at begining.

Comment: No it wouldn't cause an error with Linq To SQL and just work. What do you mean, "columnA is string at beginning"? What else could it be, if it is text or varchar(), ...?

Comment: I'm not convinced you can use an equality compare with `text`, it's a data-type that I have never used, but I do recall reading about it's issues with LINQ.  If you look at the model that's been generated, you will see what `ColumnA` looks like.

Answer (score 1):

I tried all the above-mentioned solution and none of the fixes works for me, So here I am posting the fix which works for me

```
 var result = db.Table.Where(x => Convert.ToString(x.columnA) == "A").ToList();
```

Comment: This is better than @christiandev's answer because it will not throw an exception when x.columnA is null or empty.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and none of the string conversion solutions worked for me.
The problem was that I had a `'text'` data type for this column (because I migrated it from sqlite).
Solution: just change the data type to `'nvarchar()' and regenerate the table.